# Hashing between PHP and Java

Tags: java, php, hash

I'm trying to create a hash in PHP store it in a database then verify the hash in Java. So far they both work fine independently from each other ... Java can hash and verify java, Php can hash and verify php, but they aren't playing nicely together despite my best efforts.

1. I've changed the algorithm to `sha1` in php to match javas `PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1` - Do they match?
2. I've used Base64.decodeBase64() from the apache commons codec library to decode the php base64_encode() function - is this ok?
3. I'm manually removing the algorithm "sha1:" part for java for now.

Here's the code, can you spot any reasons why the java implementation wouldn't be able to verify the hash produced by the php version? - I'm not getting error, it's just the verification is failing when the correct password is "password" for that hash.

Part 1 ... I define all the variables for PHP, the only different variable is the algorithm in use

```
define("PBKDF2_HASH_ALGORITHM", "sha1");
define("PBKDF2_ITERATIONS", 1000);
define("PBKDF2_SALT_BYTE_SIZE", 24);
define("PBKDF2_HASH_BYTE_SIZE", 24);

define("HASH_SECTIONS", 4);
define("HASH_ALGORITHM_INDEX", 0);
define("HASH_ITERATION_INDEX", 1);
define("HASH_SALT_INDEX", 2);
define("HASH_PBKDF2_INDEX", 3);
```

Part 2 ... The code to create / validate hashes in php

```
function create_hash($password)
{
    // format: algorithm:iterations:salt:hash
    $salt = base64_encode(mcrypt_create_iv(PBKDF2_SALT_BYTE_SIZE, MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM));
    return PBKDF2_HASH_ALGORITHM . ":" . PBKDF2_ITERATIONS . ":" .  $salt . ":" .
    base64_encode(pbkdf2(
        PBKDF2_HASH_ALGORITHM,
        $password,
        $salt,
        PBKDF2_ITERATIONS,
        PBKDF2_HASH_BYTE_SIZE,
        true
    ));
}

function validate_password($password, $correct_hash)
{
$params = explode(":", $correct_hash);
if(count($params) < HASH_SECTIONS)
   return false;
$pbkdf2 = base64_decode($params[HASH_PBKDF2_INDEX]);
return slow_equals(
    $pbkdf2,
    pbkdf2(
        $params[HASH_ALGORITHM_INDEX],
        $password,
        $params[HASH_SALT_INDEX],
        (int)$params[HASH_ITERATION_INDEX],
        strlen($pbkdf2),
        true
    )
);
}

// Compares two strings $a and $b in length-constant time.
function slow_equals($a, $b)
{
$diff = strlen($a) ^ strlen($b);
for($i = 0; $i < strlen($a) && $i < strlen($b); $i++)
{
    $diff |= ord($a[$i]) ^ ord($b[$i]);
}
return $diff === 0;
}

function pbkdf2($algorithm, $password, $salt, $count, $key_length, $raw_output = false)
{
$algorithm = strtolower($algorithm);
if(!in_array($algorithm, hash_algos(), true))
    trigger_error('PBKDF2 ERROR: Invalid hash algorithm.', E_USER_ERROR);
if($count <= 0 || $key_length <= 0)
    trigger_error('PBKDF2 ERROR: Invalid parameters.', E_USER_ERROR);

if (function_exists("hash_pbkdf2")) {
    // The output length is in NIBBLES (4-bits) if $raw_output is false!
    if (!$raw_output) {
        $key_length = $key_length * 2;
    }
    return hash_pbkdf2($algorithm, $password, $salt, $count, $key_length, $raw_output);
}

$hash_length = strlen(hash($algorithm, "", true));
$block_count = ceil($key_length / $hash_length);

$output = "";
for($i = 1; $i <= $block_count; $i++) {
    // $i encoded as 4 bytes, big endian.
    $last = $salt . pack("N", $i);
    // first iteration
    $last = $xorsum = hash_hmac($algorithm, $last, $password, true);
    // perform the other $count - 1 iterations
    for ($j = 1; $j < $count; $j++) {
        $xorsum ^= ($last = hash_hmac($algorithm, $last, $password, true));
    }
    $output .= $xorsum;
}

if($raw_output)
    return substr($output, 0, $key_length);
else
    return bin2hex(substr($output, 0, $key_length));
}
```

This is the java verification code:

Part 3 ... Setup the variables in java

```
public static final String PBKDF2_ALGORITHM = "PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1";
public static final int SALT_BYTE_SIZE = 24;
public static final int HASH_BYTE_SIZE = 24;
public static final int PBKDF2_ITERATIONS = 1000;

public static final int ITERATION_INDEX = 0;
public static final int SALT_INDEX = 1;
public static final int PBKDF2_INDEX = 2;
```

Part 4 ... Setup the verification part for java

```
public static boolean validatePassword(String password, String correctHash) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeySpecException {
return validatePassword(password.toCharArray(), correctHash);
}

public static boolean validatePassword(char[] password, String correctHash)
    throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeySpecException {
// Decode the hash into its parameters
String[] params = correctHash.split(":");
int iterations = Integer.parseInt(params[ITERATION_INDEX]);
byte[] salt = Base64.decodeBase64(params[SALT_INDEX]);
byte[] hash = Base64.decodeBase64(params[PBKDF2_INDEX]);
// Compute the hash of the provided password, using the same salt,
// iteration count, and hash length
byte[] testHash = pbkdf2(password, salt, iterations, hash.length);
// Compare the hashes in constant time. The password is correct if
// both hashes match.
return slowEquals(hash, testHash);
}

private static boolean slowEquals(byte[] a, byte[] b) {
int diff = a.length ^ b.length;
for (int i = 0; i < a.length && i < b.length; i++)
    diff |= a[i] ^ b[i];
return diff == 0;
}

private static byte[] pbkdf2(char[] password, byte[] salt, int iterations,
    int bytes) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeySpecException {
PBEKeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec(password, salt, iterations, bytes * 8);
SecretKeyFactory skf = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance(PBKDF2_ALGORITHM);
return skf.generateSecret(spec).getEncoded();
}
```

Step 5 ... Call it

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException,
    InvalidKeySpecException {
System.out.println(validatePassword("password", "1000:PoTTC/xEqAgH9A4vCnagBPioC71cPm+C:bLBiDjW8+VukY9PnRTOrMy/JDSfPEW8Y"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a really old question, but I found it in the process of figuring it out myself, and found out that you had pretty much everything right except for the `bytes` conversion for the `salt` and `hash`.

Anyway, for your problem, instead of using `Base64.decodeBase64(params[SALT_INDEX])`, just use `params[SALT_INDEX].getBytes()`.  This should return the proper bytecode for hash usage.

*As a side note, I don't know what library you were using, I ended up with*
`com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dv.util.Base64`

*and thus my method was actually `Base64.decode()`*

So, part 4 ends up being like this:

```
public static boolean validatePassword(String password, String correctHash) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeySpecException {
return validatePassword(password.toCharArray(), correctHash);
}

public static boolean validatePassword(char[] password, String correctHash)
    throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeySpecException {
// Decode the hash into its parameters
String[] params = correctHash.split(":");
int iterations = Integer.parseInt(params[ITERATION_INDEX]);

// these two lines were changed
byte[] salt = params[SALT_INDEX].getBytes();
byte[] hash = params[PBKDF2_INDEX].getBytes();

// Compute the hash of the provided password, using the same salt,
// iteration count, and hash length
byte[] testHash = pbkdf2(password, salt, iterations, hash.length);
// Compare the hashes in constant time. The password is correct if
// both hashes match.
return slowEquals(hash, testHash);
}

private static boolean slowEquals(byte[] a, byte[] b) {
int diff = a.length ^ b.length;
for (int i = 0; i < a.length && i < b.length; i++)
    diff |= a[i] ^ b[i];
return diff == 0;
}

private static byte[] pbkdf2(char[] password, byte[] salt, int iterations,
    int bytes) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeySpecException {
PBEKeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec(password, salt, iterations, bytes * 8);
SecretKeyFactory skf = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance(PBKDF2_ALGORITHM);
return skf.generateSecret(spec).getEncoded();
}
```

I tested this working with both your `slowEquals` function and with String comparison:

`if(Base64.encode(testHash).equals(params[PBKDF2_INDEX]))`

I used my own salt and hash generated with `PHP`'s crypto and transferred as strings into my own code, but I used all of your `PHP` code as the base of my script, and even used your `pbkdf2` function as-is.